# Resources/App Context in Presenter (MVP architecture)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, android-context, presenter

I need to sort the list using `Comparator` which depends on `Resources`. The list (data) is loaded from the repository (Model layer). How can I do this if a 
 Presenter should not have access to `Context`? Should I inject already created `Comparator`?

```
new ProductsPresenter(new ProductsRepository(), productsFragment, new ProductsComparator(context))
```

(prodcutsFragment is a View layer)

1. Is it correct?
2. What if the Presenter needs to use more `Context` depended classes? If I inject all of them, the constructor will have a lot of parameters.

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/30f7c5a16bb0854e003530e81403e922e745d311/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksPresenter.java#L122) is the code from Android blueprints where for example I'd like to add sorting the list with `Comparator` depended on Resources.

Answer (score 0):

1 - It's correct. An improvement would be to use some kind of dependency library, like Dagger, to inject the instances directly, so you don't have to write `new` in constructor

2 - IMHO the best way is to inyect classes directly, without `Context`, to make your `Presenter` decoupled of Android SDK, so you'll be able to test it more easily